# is there another way to create a text file in git bash on Windows OS?

Tags: git-bash

I tried copy con command to create a text file on a new repository using git bash but it does not seem to be working.
bash: copy: command not found, is the answer i get from git bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "Sample Text" > sampleFile.txt
```

or

```
type nul > testFile.txt
```